# How to find the sum of values at given keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a Blackjack game in Python and I need to change the hand that you're given(strings) into integer values. I made a dictionary to key each string to its respective value, but im not sure about how to turn all the strings into integers and calculate the sum

```
numbers = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
values = {
    "A": 1,
    "B": 2,
    "C": 3,
    "D": 4
}

for i in numbers:
    numbers[i] = values[i]
    print(numbers[i])
```

This is simplification of my code so far

Comment: `sum(values[n] for n in numbers)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, all that is missing is a way to accumulate the values you encounter in your loop.

```
total = 0  # start counting from 0

for k in numbers:
    total += values[k]  # for each value add it to the total

print(total)  # print the total
```

Alternatively, you can use the `sum` builtin function like so. This is probably what would be the preferred way.

```
total = sum(value[k] for k in numbers)
```

Notice that in your case, the list `numbers` corresponds exactly to the keys of the dict `values`. In your context, it does not seem it will always be the case, but if it were you could do something even simpler using the `dict.values` method.

```
total = sum(values.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to print the sum at the end of the loop, rather than printing each element in the loop.

```
for i in numbers:
    numbers[i] = values[i]
print(sum(numbers))
```